# Typing Array of T to Array of ReturnType of T

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to map a result of a parameter to a callback and I'm struggling to type that in TypeScript.
I have the following function:

```
type CustomRouteType<TParam = any> = <T>(value?: T) => TParam;
const createRoute = <TTypes extends CustomRouteType[]>
    (dictionary: RouteDictionary<TTypes>,
    callback: (...params: TTypes) => void) => {

    // Logic Here
}
createRoute(
    route`/api/someEndpoint/${Number}/${String}/test`, 
    (p1, p2) => {

});
```

The route function converts the string literal to a custom dictionary that exposes the parameters in the route, so I have no way to know up front what type the route function might return.
In the example this will return a RouteDictionary<[NumberConstructor, StringConstructor]> and the way I have set this up the p1 and p2 in the callback are those constructors, I want to map these parameters to be the type of the ReturnValue of those constructors.

Typescript only has the ReturnValue and not a ReturnValues how do I map these types so that the parameters of the callback function infer the return types I'm looking for?

For reference:

```
class RouteString { 
    constructor(public routeString: string) { } 
}
class RouteParameter<T = any> { 
    constructor(public routeString: CustomRouteType<T>) { } 
}

type RouteDictionary<TTypes extends CustomRouteType[]> = {
    routeParts: (RouteString | RouteParameter)[]
    types: TTypes
}

const route = <TParams extends any[], TTypes extends CustomRouteType<any>[]>
    (template: TemplateStringsArray, ...keys: TTypes): RouteDictionary<TTypes> => {

    let routeParts: (RouteString | RouteParameter)[] = [];
    const stringParts = template.raw || [];

    for (let partIndex = 0; partIndex < stringParts.length; partIndex++) {
        const part = stringParts[partIndex];
        const stringChunks = part.split('/').filter(chunkPart => chunkPart !== String())

        routeParts = [... routeParts, ...stringChunks.map(chunk => new RouteString(chunk))]

        if (keys.length === 0) continue
        if (keys.length < partIndex) continue

        const routeParam = keys[partIndex]
        if (!routeParam) continue

        routeParts = [...routeParts, new RouteParameter(routeParam)]
    }

    return {
        routeParts,
        types: keys
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you include the definition of `RouteDictionary` and `route` or where they come fromn ?

Comment: I didn't think it would matter for the question, I'll add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to map the tuple of functions to a tuple of return values:

```
type ReturnValuesOf<T extends Array<(...a: any[]) => any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<T[P]> : never
}
type RouteDictionary<T> = T 
type CustomRouteType<TParam = any> = <T>(value?: T) => TParam;
const createRoute = <TTypes extends CustomRouteType[]>
    (dictionary: RouteDictionary<TTypes>,
    callback: (...params: ReturnValuesOf<TTypes>) => void) => {

    // Logic Here
}

function route<T extends any[]>(s: TemplateStringsArray, ...arr: T) :T {
  return arr;
}
createRoute(    
    route`/api/someEndpoint/${Number}/${String}/test`, 
    (p1, p2) => { // p1 number, p2: string 

});
```

Comment: I still don't really  understand how this maps the types correctly.
But it does map the types correctly!

Comment: @MarvinBrouwer it's just a mapped type .. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types The handbook describes it for objects works for tuples too

Comment: I see, I had some difficulty understanding what the spread operator meant.
But I see it now, you're mapping the type of the array to basically any type of function with any amount of parameters